# Is water necessary when cooking meat in a pressure cooker

Tags: pork, pressure-cooker, ribs

I recently bought packaged pork ribs, 3.5 lbs, preseasoned with whiskey black pepper. I was planning on cooking it in an instant pot, but I'm still a bit of a novice. Should I just throw the ribs in and cook it, or should I throw some liquid in the bottom?

Comment: related https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/67200/when-cooking-pulled-pork-in-a-slow-cooker-should-the-meat-be-submerged-in-liqui?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I threw a trivet rack in the bottom with a cup of water and 1/4 cup of apple cider vinegar; they came out fantastic.